# Calc not working on server , yet works on local

Tags: c#

I have a four textboxs, the first one sums a column from a gridview and the 2nd box should multiplies the first box by the last box, the third box should add box two and one. This works on my local pc yet on the server it gives me the error input is not in the correct format. Any help is welcome.

- textbox24 = 1.14
- textbox 21 = 5234
- textbox 22= multiply box24 * box21
- textbox 23 = box21 + box22
- English - South Africa - both server and local pc

Comment: What about the regional/language settings on the client and on the server? The error message points in the direction that the input is not formatted in the way that the program expects it. This is often related to regional settings or cultures.

Comment: It could be the culture settings, some countries use a `.` to separate the whole number from the decimal and some use `,`.

Comment: You can check the current settings by accessing `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` on your local machine and on the server.

Comment: Im not understanding you fully, scoregraphic

Answer (score 0):

[Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243196/calc-not-working-on-server-yet-works-on-local#comment33779574_22243196) and [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243196/calc-not-working-on-server-yet-works-on-local#comment33779578_22243196) are right. This should be a culture difference between your local pc and your server. You can check them from Regional and Language Options part.

[`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses current thread culture.

From *documentation*;

> Using the ToDouble(String) method is equivalent to passing value to
>   the `Double.Parse(String)` method. value is interpreted by using the
>   **formatting conventions of the current thread culture.**

That means if your textboxes have [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your decimal values, and these properties are not equal for local pc's culture and your server culture, it is too normal to get [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.FormatException.aspx).

But since you never mentioned about your textbox values, your local culture and your server culture, we never know what exact problem is.

> They said, I can change the settings from the web.config file, does
>   anyone know how to do this ?

Read [`How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

Comment: I am checking with the hosting company, I will ensure to get back to you guys, thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: They said, I can change the settings from the web.config file, does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: @user3012159 Updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Soner, The value is the textbox are currency numbers, will this affect it in anyway ?

Comment: I have changed the config file, and still nothing... Is there another way to do my calculation ?

Comment: @user3012159 Please update your question the values of `TextBox21.Text`, `TextBox22.Text`, `TextBox23.Text`, `TextBox24.Text`, your local pc's culture and your server culture (take a look at the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` of both pc and server).

Answer (score 0):

You are using ConvertToDouble before show the text in the textBox22

Your commented line is good, the one below the comment, no ;)

```
public void Multiply()
    {
        try
        {

            double vat = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox24.Text);
            double tot = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox21.Text);
            double ans = tot * vat;

                //TextBox22.Text = ans.ToString().Trim(); 
                TextBox22.Text = ans.ToString().Trim();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TextBox22.Text = e.Message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yip, you right! I was testing coz I am pulling my hair out